# Where can you find historical PEs of US indices?

Tags: etf, market-indexes, price-earnings-ratio

**Indices tracking ETFs**

```
* DIAMONDS Trust I (ticker: DIA) tracks DJIA
* SPDRs (ticker: SPY) tracks S&P 500
* NASDAQ 100 Trust (ticker: QQQQ) tracks NASDAQ 100
* iShares Russell 2000 (ticker: IWM) tracks Russell 2000
* MidCap SPDRs (ticker: MDY) tracks S&P MidCap 400
* Total Stock Market VIPERs (ticker: VTI) tracks Wilshire 5000
```

([source](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3158/how-to-calculate-pe-ratios-for-indices-such-as-djia/3168#3168))

**The PEs of the ETFs**

```
PE(DIA)=3.08 
PE(IWM)=2.49 
PE(VTI)=4.09 
PE(DVY)=3.45
```

Where can I find historical PE values for indices with clearly shown methods? By method, I mean the way how PE is calculated.

Comment: In its current form, this question suffers from temporal issues.  That is, it would be considered too localized (in time).  I suggest that you rephrase it in a form that is more timeless.  In other words, I would ask questions 2, 3 or 4.  Also, generally try to keep it to one question, if possible.  Questions 3 & 4 may be related enough for one question.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  On a side-note, here are some details on how the comments and notifications work: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Internet sites**

- [S&P 500 during 1936-2008](http://www2.standardandpoors.com/spf/xls/index/sp500pe_ratio.xls)
- [DOW indices, Russell 2000, S&P, Nasdaq Composite](http://online.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3021-peyield.html?mod=mdc_h_usshl)
- [S&P 500 graph, not trust-worthy the later years because S&P 500 did not exist that time!](http://www.multpl.com/)
- [PEs of different sectors](http://biz.yahoo.com/ic/ind_index.html)
- [historical graph of S&P until 2005, again the last part is deduced some odd way](http://web.archive.org/web/%2a/http://www.comstockfunds.com/files/NLPP00000%5C026.pdf#search=%22price%20earnings%20ratio%20s%26p500%22)
- [historical DJIA PE at the bottom](http://www.gold-eagle.com/editorials_05/lundeen110807.html)

**Books**

- [Irrational Exuberance: page 5 discusses historical PEs, probably covers more about PEs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0767923634)

**Academic**

- [PE analysis with Shiller](http://www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/data/peratio.html)
- [data about dividend yield, PE, -- by Shiller (author of Irrational Exuberance- book above)](http://www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/data.htm)

Comment: A note on multpl.com: `The figures on this site are the PE10 or Shiller PE` http://www.multpl.com/faq

Comment: @GeorgeMarian Thank you for pointing that out. But also, thank you for drawing my attention to a nice website in general, multpl.com This is a good all around answer actually!